# Creating 2 additional columns based on past dates - PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Seeking some help after spending alot of time on searching but to no avail and decided to post this here as I'm rather new to SQL, so any help is greatly appreciated. I've tried a few functions but can't seem to get it right. e.g. GROUP BY, BETWEEN etc

On the PrestoSQL server, I have a table as shown below starting with columns Date, ID and COVID. Using **GROUP BY** ID, I would like to create a column ***EverCOVIDBefore*** which looks back at all past dates of the **COVID** column to see if there was ever COVID = 1 or not, as well as another column called ***COVID_last_2_mth*** which checks if there was ever COVID = 1 within the past 2 months

*(Highlighted columns are my expected outcomes)*

[image]

**Link to dataset:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sc5Olrx9g2A36WnLcCFMU0YTQ3-qWROU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text or table as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 1) PrestoSQL != Postgres . Be more specific about how Postgres fits into this, if at all. 2) Look at [Window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html?highlight=window)

Comment: How exactly do you define two months? 60 days, or the same month-day two months ago?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *,
  max(covid) over(partition by id order by date) as ever_covid_before,
  max(covid) over(partition by id order by date 
    range between interval '2 month' preceding and current row) 
    as covid_last_two_months
from t
```

Result:

```
 date        id  covid  ever_covid_before  covid_last_two_months 
 ----------- --- ------ ------------------ --------------------- 
 2020-01-15  1   0      0                  0                     
 2020-02-15  1   0      0                  0                     
 2020-03-15  1   1      1                  1                     
 2020-04-15  1   0      1                  1                     
 2020-05-15  1   0      1                  1                     
 2020-06-15  1   0      1                  0                     
 2020-01-15  2   0      0                  0                     
 2020-02-15  2   1      1                  1                     
 2020-03-15  2   0      1                  1                     
 2020-04-15  2   0      1                  1                     
 2020-05-15  2   0      1                  0                     
 2020-06-15  2   1      1                  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XO4TSWEK).